# php mysql select dynamically within 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

> table A 
>  id name Bid Cid Wheretolook
>  1  aaa 
>        1        0
>        B
>  2  bbb 
>        2       0
>        B
>  3  bbb 
>        0        1
>        C
>
> Table B
>  id transactiondetails
>  1      
>   zzz 
>  2       xxx
>
> Table C 
>  id transactiondetails 
>  1
>        yyy

I have 3 tables right here table A holds foreign key for the two tables Table B and Table C. These two tables don't have the same information inside that's what I'm suppose to get. Is there a way to select all of the information from table B and C using mysql SELECT statement to gather all the transactiondetails

Comment: are you looking for a FULL JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  a.name, 
  COALESCE(b.transactiondetails, c.transactiondetails) AS transactiondetails
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.Bid = b.id
LEFT JOIN TableC c ON a.Cid = c.id
```

The `Wheretolook` column seems to be unnecessary if there must be one `0` in Bid and Cid.